# Remove every 8th char from a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string, which I want to iterate through and remove every 8th char. I have been trying with an modulo operation which check if `i % 8 == 0`. However, since I remove every 8th char the length of the string decreases, and I am therefore unable to perform that operation.

```
StringBuilder str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

    // Every 8th element should be discarded    
    if (i > 7 && i % 8 == 0) {
        str.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
}

System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());
```

The length of the string is in the beginning 64, and after the for loop 57, which should be 56.

Comment: You can't modify the size of an array while iterating through it. Make a copy, modify the copy, and when you're done you can forget the original

Comment: Why not create a new string where you add the chars if they are mod 0 through 7, and ignore the 8th?

Comment: Note that deleting elements from an array would mean you'd have to shift the other elements left by one place and handle the indices accordingly (e.g. index 15 would become 14 when you remove the element at index 7 etc.). Because of that it's often easier to either make a copy and just skip elements or if it needs to be inplace do it back-to-front.

Comment: You could also use a regex: `String shortened = str.replaceAll( "(.{7}).", "$1" );` This will replace each sequence of 8 characters with the first 7 thus effectively skipping every 8th.

Comment: Why are you using a String of 64 binary digits when you could just use a `long`?

Comment: Yep, in general, algorithms that modify their inputs are harder to write and read. So, don't do that. Keep the input the original input and if you need a buffer to build the output, do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you don't adjust `i` when removing characters.

Let's visualize that. You want to remove the following marked characters ("every 8th element"):

```
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
```

Now we're at `i = 7` and remove that character, but because you don't adjust `i` accordingly the markers keep the same:

```
110011001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
```

Let's do that for `1 = 15` to `i = 55`:

```
11001100101101100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  //i = 15
1100110010110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000   //i = 23
110011001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000    //i = 31
11001100101101100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000     //i = 39
1100110010110110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000      //i = 47
110011001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000       //i = 55   
       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
```

As you can see, all but the last marker point to a valid character but you won't reach `i = 63` because after the first time you remove a character there only are 63 left in the string and thus a max index of 62.

That's why your resulting string has 57 instead of 56 characters, the last "remove" operation doesn't run (and the others except the first remove the wrong elements).

To fix that iterate backwards, i.e. from `i = str.length() - 1` to `i = 0`. Then you can remove every element where `(i + 1) % 8 == 0`.

Alternatively, as I said in my comment, use a regex: `String shortened = str.replaceAll( "(.{7}).", "$1" );`

This will match any sequence of 7 characters followed by another (8th) character and replaces that with the first group of 7 (thus skipping the 8th).

Comment: I like your regex. Elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is not `deleteCharAt` method in `String`, so I suppose you meant `StringBuilder`?

You can just reverse the direction of the for loop, so that it starts from the end of the string:

```
    String str = "11111111811111118";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
    System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Every 8th element should be discarded

        if (i > 7 && i % 8 == 0) {
            builder.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(builder+ " " + builder.length());
```

By deleting chars from the end of the string, the indices of the chars to be removed no longer changes as you move along the string.

Comment: Using original string: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 64,length 64`

Comment: @Andreas Oops! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use regex and achieve it in two lines of code like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    String replacedStr = str.replaceAll("([01]{7})[01]", "$1");

    System.out.println(str.toString() + " " + str.length());
    System.out.println(replacedStr.toString() + " " + replacedStr.length());
}
```

This gives perfectly correct output,

```
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
11001100101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56
```

**Alternatively, you can follow this traditional solution like you attempted.**

Strings in java are immutable. So instead you should create a StringBuilder object and keep copying every character, except 8th character.

For correctly counting every 8th character, initialize your for loop index run from 1 rather than 0, like in this code, which will eradicate every 8th character effectively where you wanted to do `if (i%8==0)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());

    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++) {
        // Every 8th element should be discarded

        if (i % 8 == 0) {
            // str.deleteCharAt(i);
        } else {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i-1));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString() + " " + sb.length());
}
```

And this gives following output,

```
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
11001100101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56
```

You can verify here where only every 8th character is gone in this output.

Comment: But the second output should have a length of 56

Answer (score 0):

`String` doesn't have a `deleteCharAt()` method. If it did, it would return the update string, since `String` is immutablem so code would have had to be `str = str.deleteCharAt(i);`.

You could use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead, since it does have a [`deleteCharAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt-int-) method.

To delete every 8th character, start at the end. That way index values are unaffected by already deleted characters, which is your current problem.

```
String str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = (buf.length() - 1) / 8 * 8; i >= 0; i -= 8)
    buf.deleteCharAt(i);
str = buf.toString();
System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());
```

*Output*

```
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
10011001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56
```

**UPDATE**

The above code deletes the 1st, 9th, 17th, ... character, i.e. characters at index 0, 8, 16, ..., which is in accordance with "remove every 8th char" and "check if i % 8 == 0" mentioned in the question.

If code should delete the 8th, 16th, 24th, ... character, i.e. characters at index 7, 15, 23, ..., then change initialization of `i` as follows:

```
for (int i = (buf.length() - 8) & ~7 | 7; i >= 0; i -= 8)
    buf.deleteCharAt(i);
```

*Output*

1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
11001100101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56

Comment: You removed first character but OP wants to remove every 8th character.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I am removing "every 8th"
 character, starting with the 1st character, which is what the check `i % 8 == 0` does. OP didn't specify that it should start with 8th character, i.e. `i % 8 == 7`.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned anywhere that he wants to remove starting from the very first character in his post. Every 8th character means, you skip the first 7 character then remove the next character, and continue like that. In your output string, you have clearly removed the very first digit, which I think you should correct. And `i % 8 == 0` selects the very first character which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Strings are starting with 0. Therefore the 8th element has the index 7 and has to be removed as well, which you don't do in your loop. I'd write it like that (but noting that this might not be the most elegant solution):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

    System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());
    int idx = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        idx++;
        if (idx == 8) {
            idx = 0;
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString() + " " + sb.length());

}
```

Outputs:

```
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
11001100101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is using `substring()` method.

> substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) Returns a new string that is a
>   substring of this string.

In every turn add 7 chars of the string to the new string and skip the 8th element of the string: `sb.append(str.substring(start, start+7));`

In first turn:

```
str.substring(0, 7) -> "1100110"
start += 8; -> start = 8;
```

In second turn:

```
str.substring(8, 15) -> "0101101"
start += 8; -> start = 23;
```

...

So the 8th element/the element has the index 7 `("0")` has been skipped.

```
    String str = "1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

    int length = str.length();
    int start = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while((start+7)<length) {
        sb.append(str.substring(start, start+7));
        start += 8;
    }
    if(start<length) {
        sb.append(str.substring(start, length));
    }

    System.out.println(sb + " " + sb.length());
    System.out.println(str + " " + str.length());
```

Output:

```
11001100101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 56
1100110001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 64
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string does not contain the char with ASCII value 0, convert the string to a char array and change every 8th char with the char with ASCII value 0, then reconstruct the string and replace all chars with ASCII value 0 with "":

```
    String str = "0123456701234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567";
    System.out.println("initial = " + str);

    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 7; i < array.length; i = i + 8) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    str = String.valueOf(array).replace(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(0)), "");
    System.out.println("final   = " + str);
```

will print:

```
initial = 0123456701234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567
final   = 01234560123456012345601234560123456012345601234560123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `StringBuilder::deleteCharAt` changes the size of the underlying sequence, you need to process the target string in reverse order.

This solution is based on streams.

```
// create target string
String s = Stream.generate(() -> IntStream.range(0, 10))
    .limit(10)
    .map(stream -> stream.mapToObj(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

// delete first element or not?
boolean removeFirst = false;
IntStream.range(removeFirst ? 0 : 1, s.length())
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()) // reverse number stream
    .filter(i -> i % 8 == 0) // only keep multiples of 8
    .forEach(sb::deleteCharAt);

System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This is the output it produces

> 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
>
> 123456790123457890123567890134567891234567901234578901235678901345678912345679012345789

The first element missing is the 8, then 6 (16), then the 4 (24), etc.